# How parse csv with '\n' symbols in cell?

Tags: javascript, csv, parsing

I have csv-file. And i want to use only native javascript for parse this file. some cells of this file contains '\n' symbols. Its problem.
js:

```
init();

function init() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '2.csv',
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(data) {
      //console.log(data);
      csvParse(data);
    },
    error: function(textStatus) {
      console.log(textStatus);
    }
  });
};

function csvParse(data) {
  var temporaryArray = data.split(/\r\n|\n/);
  console.log(temporaryArray);
  var finalArray = [];

  temporaryArray.forEach(function(line) {
    var lineArr = line.split(';');
    finalArray.push(lineArr);
  })  

  console.log(finalArray);
}
```

Live demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y2Rm8mjZWjs62Lndf8Lp?p=preview).

The problem is that instead of the 17 elements of the array I get 11.

Comment: You need to encode the data before saving it.

Comment: But i not save data, i get csv-files from managers

Comment: Is the count of the "cells" exactly the same on every "row"?

Comment: @Teemu yes. every row have the same number cells

Comment: In that case you could iterate through the data, push characters to an array until you've found a certain amount of semicolons, then start a new array, discard the next line-break, and continue pushing characters to a new array. Though this will work only, if the last cell on a row doesn't contain line-breaks.